# Variable assigned from a function's return in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Let's take this for example:

```
function test(i, total) {
    return total + i * 100 / 999 * -124 / 333;
}
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    total = test(i, total);
    console.log(total);
}
```

When testing it, I see that it works synchronously -- the for loop will wait until test(i, total) has returned its value before going through the next iteration.

However there are other cases where a loop would keep on going and even finish, before a function was even done doing its function. If the test function took 3 seconds to return, why does the loop wait on that? Is it because there is nothing of async nature in the test function? I tried setting a setTimeout of 3 seconds in the test function and then I'd get undefined from the console log.

Comment: Invocation in _JavaScript_ is blocking, but _JavaScript_ doesn't have a blocking wait/sleep method and instead uses a non-blocking callback for that. Logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "If the test function took 3 seconds to return, why does the loop wait
>   on that? Is it because there is nothing of async nature in the test
>   function?"

Exactly. The execution of functions is synchronous in Javascript, like in almost every other language. The execution is done along a single path, so when you call a function it will complete before returning and the code after the call can continue.

If you use asynchronous code in a function (for example with `setTimeout`), then the asynchronous code will be put on hold until the rest of the code has executed and the browser get the control back, as Javascript is single threaded.

If you call `test` 101 times in your loop and it uses `setTimeout` each time, then there is 101 pieces of code that waits to run while the loop completes. Those 101 pieces of code can not run until after the loop has completed. The code that you have put on hold can't provide a value to return from the function, as the function returns before the code can run.

To run code asynchronously you would use a callback that gets called when the function has completed. Example:

```
function test(i, callback) {
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    var result = i * 100 / 999 * -124 / 333;
    callback(result);
  }, 1000);
}

var total = 0;
var resultCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  test(i, handleCallback);
}

function handleCallback(value) {
  total += value;
  resultCount++;
  if (resultCount == 101) {
    console.log(total);
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7VgWV/

Answer (score 1):

Function calls are synchronous and single threaded in Javascript. This is per the language design. When you call the `test` function from the loop, the loop waits till the function returns.

When you call `setTimeout`, it creates a *timer* and returns immediately. It does not wait for the *timer* to be triggered (even for the first time). The *timer* is triggered asynchronously.

For more info, see [Is JavaScript guaranteed to be single-threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded) and read about [web workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because JavaScript is single-threaded. Your code is single-threaded.